# SharePoint 2016 user profile service issue

Tags: user-profile-service, 2016

I have the User Profile service for Sharepoint 2016 completely setup. I run the full import and users were populated. I now update a user in AD and it does not update in SharePoint.

The only indicator I can find is a couple of log entries similar to:

Exception while updating properties for 'XXXX\XXX': Property: MailNickName, Exception Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyNotDefinedException: Property Not Defined: MailNickName.  An administrator must create this property in the Profile Administration tool.

this is coming up for most users. Any thoughts on where to start looking for this issue.?

Comment: once you update in AD, you'd need to run another sync in order for it to reflect in SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is some profile corruption issue. as per [this MSDN link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sajiths/2014/12/03/sp2013-adimport-more-than-one-dn-specified-for-the-same-profile/). you have to follow these steps:

1. Run following powershell command and make note of guid of UPSA. 
   Get-SPServiceApplication
2. Run following commands one by one. 
   $u = Get-SPServiceApplication 
   Set-SPProfileServiceApplication $u -GetNonImportedObjects $true # Here you will get the results for profiles 'IsImportedvalue = 0' from ProfileDB 
   Ran Set-SPProfileServiceApplication $u -PurgeNonImportedObjects $true # This cmdlet will mark the profiles for deletion and need MySiteCleanup job to delete those which are marked for deletion. If MySite is part of one user that added in missing profile, the same job will delete those MySites as well. Here is the detailed implications while running My Site Cleanup job.
3. Run Incremental profile import. Query following against ProfileDB and we should get no results. 
   select * from DNLookup where isimported !=1  # Make sure you have backup of profile database before running any queries against it.
4. Go ahead and run Full profile Import, once the above query returns no result.

Answer (score 0):

We had migrated the content from SharePoint 2013. (did not migrate the UPS, only content). The old farm was still running and the UPS was running on the old farm. As soon as that was shut off, the AD Sync imported correctly.

Doesn't totally make sense, but I suspect something in AD was getting confused in regards to the change log. They were different servers and different accounts so no totally sure unless they were attempting connections at the same time maybe.

Not truly sure, but it is now fixed.